# Bootbox dialog appearing after knockout function has finished but should be first

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, bootbox

This is probably straightforward for someone.

I'm working on a site which has bootbox implemented. I've tried to use a simple dialog in the same way it's used across the site, however the dialog pop up always appears after my slow code has run.

I have a function self.myFunction  which has a loop that is a bit slow (due to how knockout handles foreach),so the pop up should be shown whilst the loop is running, but waits until the loop is finished then appears.

I've tried changing the order of things in my code. I've tried having the dialog inside the loop (which technically works but not what I need). I tried putting a timeout just after the call to make the dialog appear but that also waited until the loop had finished before being executed.

```
self.checkPermCol = function () {

    //call bootbox
    bootbox.dialog({
        size: 'small',
        message: '<div class="text-center"><i class="fal fa-spin fa-spinner"></i>Please wait...</div>'
    });


    //some logic
    var setTo = "N";
    if ($('#' + event.target.id).prop("checked")) {
        setTo = "Y";
    }
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.user().Securities(), function (security) {
        security[event.target.id](setTo);
    });


    //dismiss bootbox
    bootbox.hideAll();

    return true;
};
```

I expect the pop up to be shown whilst the looping through the stuff, and for it to disappear immediately after the loop.

The pop up appears after the loop, and is immediately dismissed (I only see it if I remove the hideAll);

Cheers, any help at all is appreciated

Comment: I'm not seeing anything special that might cause this. I suggest you put some console.log() statements to see what gets hit when. Perhaps some other process is interfering.

Comment: I've done that with nothing special showing in my results either. e.g. sticking an alert in immediately after the bootbox call,pops up the alert before the bootbox.

Comment: have you tried bootbox.alert() instead of bootbox.dialog()?

Comment: yeah, makes no difference at all. The dialog/alert/whatever always appears after anything else within the same function :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute the rest of the code once the modal shows like this:

```
dialog.on('shown.bs.modal', function(e){
    // Do something with the dialog just after it has been shown to the user...
});
```

Reference here: http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html